# Парсинг сайта на python и расшифровка текста

Tags: python, парсер

Пробую парсить сайт
python
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

```
req = Request('https://lord4.lordfilm.lu/filmy/', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:105.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/105.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()

print(webpage)
```

Выводит html код пример:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html lang="ru">\n<head>\n<meta charset="utf-8">\n<title>\xd0\xa4\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd0\xbc\xd1\x8b \xd1\x81\xd0\xbc\xd0\xbe\xd1\x82\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82\xd1\x8c \xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9\xd0\xbd, \xd0\xba\xd0\xbe\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb5 \xd1\x83\xd0\xb6\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xb2\xd1\x8b\xd1\x88\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb8 \xd0\xb2 HD 720 - 1080 \xd1\x85\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd1\x88\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbc \xd0\xba\xd0\xb0\xd1\x87\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xb1\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81\xd0\xbf\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd1\x82\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbe</title>\n<meta name="description" content="\xd0\xa1\xd0\xbc\xd0\xbe\xd1\x82\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82\xd1\x8c \xd0\xb1\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81\xd0\xbf\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd1\x82\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbe \xd1\x83\xd0\xb6\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xb2\xd1\x8b\xd1\x88\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb4\xd1\x88\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb5 \xd1\x84\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd0\xbc\xd1\x8b 2019 - 2020 \xd0\xb3\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb0 \xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9\xd0\xbd. \xd0\x9b\xd1\x83\xd1\x87\xd1\x88\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xba\xd0\xb0\xd1\x87\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb2\xd0\xbe HD \xd0\xb8 \xd0\xbe\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb2\xd1\x83\xd1\x87\xd0\xba\xd0\xb8. \xd0\x91\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb7 \xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb3\xd0\xb8\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd1\x86\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb8 \xd0\xb8 \xd1\x81\xd0\xbc\xd1\x81!">\n<meta name="keywords" content="">\n<link rel="search" type="application/opensearchdescription+xml" href="https://lord4.lordfilm.lu/index.php?do=opensearch" title="\xd0\xa4\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd0\xbc\xd1\x8b, \xd1\x81\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8b, \xd0\xbc\xd1\x83\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd1\x82\xd1\x84\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd0\xbc\xd1\x8b \xd0\xb4\xd0\xbe\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd1\x83\xd0\xbf\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9\xd0\xbd - LORDFILM">\n<link rel="canonical" href="https://lord4.lordfilm.lu/filmy/">\n<meta name="robots" content="noarchive" />\n<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />\n<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/templates/lordfilm/images/favicon.png" />\n<link href="/templates/lordfilm/style/styles.css?=v17" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />\n<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600|Oswald:700&amp;subset=cyrillic" rel="stylesheet">\n<meta name="theme-color" content="#111" />\n<script>navigator.serviceWorker.register(\'/pushlflu.js\');</script>\n<meta name="pushverification" content="gtzxrfqj" />\n</head>\n<body>\n<script src="https://kodir2.github.io/actualize.js" async></script>\n<script src="https://hdvb-player.github.io/actualize.js" async></script>\n<div class="wrap">\n<div class="wrap-center wrap-main">\n<header class="header" id="header">\n<div class="header-in wrap-center fx-row fx-middle">\n<a href="/" class="logo"><img src="/templates/lordfilm/images/logo.png" alt="lordfilm" /></a>\n<div class="btn-menu"><span class="fa fa-bars"></span></div>\n<ul class="hmenu for_open fx-row to-mob">\n<li><a href="/filmy/">\xd0\xa4\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd0\xbc\xd1\x8b</a>\n<div class="hidden-menu clearfix">\n<ul class="hm-col">\n<li><a href="/filmy/">\xd0\x92\xd1\x81\xd0\xb5</a></li>\n<li><a href="/filmy/netflix-f/">NETFLIX</a></li>\n<li>\xd0\x9f\xd0\xbe \xd0\xb3\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb4\xd1\x83:</li>\n<li><a href="/filmy/2022-f/">2022</a></li>\n<li><a href="/filmy/2021-f/">2021</a></li>\n<li><a href="/filmy/2020-f/">2020</a></li>\n<li><a href="/filmy/2019-f/">2019</a></li>\n<li><a href="/filmy/2018-f/">2018</a></li>\n<li><a href="/filmy/2017-f/">2017</a></li>\n<li>\xd0\x9f\xd0\xbe \xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbc:</li>\n<li><a href="/filmy/zarubezhnye-f/">\xd0\x97\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd1\x83\xd0\xb1\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb6\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb5</a></li>\n<li><a href="/filmy/indijskie-f/">\xd0\x98\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb9\xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb5</a></li>\n<li><a href="/filmy/tureckie-f/">\xd0\xa2\xd1\x83\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd1\x86\xd0\xba\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb5</a></li>\n<li><a href="/filmy/francuzskie-f/">\xd0\xa4\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd1\x86\xd1\x83\xd0\xb7\xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb5</a></li>\n</ul>\n<ul class="hm-col">\n<li>\xd0\x9f\xd0\xbe \xd0\xb6\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbc:</li>\n<li><a href="/filmy/biograficheskie-f/">\xd0\x91\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb3\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd1\x84\xd0\xb8\xd1\x87\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb5</a></li>\n<li><a href="/filmy/myuzikly-f/">\xd0\x9c\xd1\x8e\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8b</a></li>\n<li><a href="/filmy/boeviki-f/">\xd0\x91\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd0\xb8</a></li>\n<li><a href="/filmy/vesterny-f/">\xd0\x92\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b</a></li>\n<li><a href="/filmy/voennye-f/">\xd0\x92\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb5</a></li>\n<li><a href="/filmy/dokumentalnye-f/">\xd0\x94\xd0\xbe\xd0\xba\xd1\x83\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb5</a></li>\n<li><a href="/filmy/detektivy-f/">\xd0\x94\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\xd0\xba\xd1\x82\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd1\x8b</a></li>\n<li><a href="/filmy/detskie-f/">\xd0\x94\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82\xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb5</a></li>\n<li><a href="/filmy/dramy-f/">\xd0\x94\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbc\xd1\x8b</a></li>\n<li><a href="/filmy/istoricheskie-f/">\xd0\x98\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd1\x87\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb5</a></li>\n<li><a href="/filmy/komedii-f/">\xd0\x9a\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb8</a></li>\n<li><a href="/filmy/korotkometrazhki-f/">\xd0\x9a\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd1\x82\xd0\xba\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb6\xd0\xba\xd0\xb8</a></li>\n<li><a href="/filmy/kriminal-f/">\xd0\x9a\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb</a></li>\n</ul>\n<ul class="hm-col">\n<li><a href="/filmy/melodramy-f/">\xd0\x9c\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb4\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbc\xd1\x8b</a></li>\n<li><a href="/filmy/muzykalnye-f/">\xd0\x9c\xd1\x83\xd0\xb7\xd1\x8b\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb5</a></li>\n<li><a href="/filmy/nuar-f/">\xd0\x9d\xd1\x83\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80</a></li>\n<li><a href="/filmy/priklyucheniya-f/">\xd0\x9f\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8e\xd1\x87\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f</a></li>\n<li><a href="/filmy/semejnye-f/">\xd0\xa1\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb9\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb5</a></li>\n<li><a href="/filmy/sport-f/">\xd0\xa1\xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd1\x82</a></li>\n<li><a href="/filmy/trillery-f/">\xd0\xa2\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd1\x8b</a></li>\n<li><a href="/filmy/uzhasy-f/">\xd0\xa3\xd0\xb6\xd0\xb0\xd1\x81\xd1\x8b</a></li>\n<li><a href="/filmy/fantastika-f/">\xd0\xa4\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0</a></li>\n<li><a href="/filmy/fehntezi-f/">\xd0\xa4\xd1\x8d\xd0\xbd\xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb8</a></li>\n</ul>\n</div>\n</li>\n<li><a href="/serialy/">\xd0\xa1\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8b</a>\n<div class="hidden-menu clearfix">\n<ul class="hm-col">\n<li><a href="/serialy/">\xd0\x92\xd1\x81\xd0\xb5</a></li>\n<li><a href="/serialy/netflix-s/">NETFLIX</a></li>\n<li><a href="/doramy-s/">\xd0\x94\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbc\xd1\x8b</a></li>\n<li><a href="/doramy-s/netflix-d-s/">\xd0\x94\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbc\xd1\x8b NETFLIX</a></li>\n<li><a href="/multfilmy/multserial-s/">\xd0\x9c\xd1\x83\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd1\x82\xd1\x81\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8b</a></li>\n<li>\xd0\x9f\xd0\xbe \xd0\xb3\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb4\xd1\x83:</li>\n<li><a href="/serialy/2022-s/">2022</a></li>\n<li><a href="/serialy/2021-s/">2021</a></li>\n<li><a href="/serialy/2020-s/">2020</a></li>\n<li><a href="/serialy/2019-s/">2019</a></li>\n<li><a href="/serialy/2018-s/">2018</a></li>\n<li>\xd0\x9f\xd0\xbe \xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbc:</li>\n<li><a href="/serialy/zarubezhnye-s/">\xd0\x97\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd1\x83\xd0\xb1\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb6\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb5</a></li>\n<li><a href="/serialy/indijskie-s/">\xd0\x98\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb9\xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb5</a></li>\n<li><a href="/serialy/tureckie-s/">\xd0\xa2\xd1\x83\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd1\x86\xd0\xba\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb5</a></li>\n</ul>\n<ul class="hm-col">\n<li>\xd0\x9f\xd0\xbe \xd0\xb6\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbc:</li>\n<li><a href="/serialy/biograficheskie-s/">\xd0\x91\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb3\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd1\x84\xd0\xb8\xd1\x87\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb5</a></li>\n<li><a href="/serialy/boeviki-s/">\xd0\x91\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd0\xb8</a></li>\n<li><a href="/serialy/vesterny-s/">\xd0\x92\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b</a></li>\n<li><a href="/serialy/voennye-s/">\xd0\x92\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb5</a></li>\n<li><a href="/serialy/dokumentalnye-s/">\xd0\x94\xd0\xbe\xd0\xba\xd1\x83\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb5</a></li>\n<li><a href="/serialy/detektivy-s/">\xd0\x94\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\xd0\xba\xd1\x82\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd1\x8b</a></li>\n<li><a href="/serialy/dramy-s/">\xd0\x94\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbc\xd1\x8b</a></li>\n<li><a href="/serialy/istoricheskie-s/">\xd0\x98\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd1\x87\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb5</a></li>\n<li><a href="/serialy/komedii-s/">\xd0\x9a\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb8</a></li>\n</ul>\n<ul class="hm-col">\n<li><a href="/serialy/kriminal-s/">\xd0\x9a\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb</a></li>\n<li><a href="/serialy/melodramy-s/">\xd0\x9c\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb4\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbc\xd1\x8b</a></li>\n<li><a href="/serialy/priklyucheniya-s/">\xd0\x9f\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8e\xd1\x87\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f</a></li>\n<li><a href="/serialy/semejnye-s/">\xd0\xa1\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb9\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb5</a></li>\n<li><a href="/serialy/sport-s/">\xd0\xa1\xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd1\x82</a></li>\n<li><a href="/serialy/teleperedachi-s/">\xd0\xa2\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbf\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb0\xd1\x87\xd0\xb8</a></li>\n<li><a href="/serialy/trillery-s/">\xd0\xa2\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd1\x8b</a></li>\n<li><a href="/serialy/uzhasy-s/">\xd0\xa3\xd0\xb6\xd0\xb0\xd1\x81\xd1\x8b</a></li>\n<li><a href="/serialy/fantastika-s/">\xd0\xa4\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0</a></li>\n<li><a href="/serialy/fehntezi-s/">\xd0\xa4\xd1\x8d\xd0\xbd\xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb8</a></li>\n</ul>\n</div>\n</li>\n<li><a href="/multfilmy/">\xd0\x9c\xd1\x83\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd1\x82\xd1\x84\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd0\xbc\xd1\x8b</a>\n<div class="hidden-menu clearfix">\n<ul class="hm-col">\n<li><a href="/multfilmy/">\xd0\x92\xd1\x81\xd0\xb5</a></li>\n<li><a href="/multfilmy/netflix-m/">NETFLIX</a></li>\n<li>\xd0\x9f\xd0\xbe \xd0\xb3\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb4\xd1\x83:</li>\n<li><a href="/multfilmy/2022-m/">2022</a></li>\n<li><a href="/multfilmy/2021-m/">2021</a></li>\n<li><a href="/multfilmy/2020-m/">2020</a></li>\n<li><a href="/multfilmy/2019-m/">2019</a></li>\n<li><a href="/multfilmy/2018-m/">2018</a></li>\n<li><a href="/multfilmy/2017-m/">2017</a></li>\n<li>\xd0\x9f\xd0\xbe \xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbc:</li>\n<li><a href="/multfilmy/zarubezhnye-m/">\xd0\x97\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd1\x83\xd0\xb1\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb6\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb5</a></li>\n</ul>\n<ul class="hm-col">\n<li>\xd0\x9f\xd0\xbe \xd0\xb6\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbc:</li>\n<li><a href="/multfilmy/myuzikly-m/">\xd0\x9c\xd1\x8e\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8b</a></li>\n<li><a href="/multfilmy/boeviki-m/">\xd0\x91\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd0\xb8</a></li>\n<li><a href="/multfilmy/detskie-m/">\xd0\x94\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82\xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb5</a></li>\n<li><a href="/multfilmy/dramy-m/">\xd0\x94\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbc\xd1\x8b</a></li>\n<li><a href="/multfilmy/komedii-m/">\xd0\x9a\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb8</a></li>\n<li><a href="/multfilmy/melodramy-m/">\xd0\x9c\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb4\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbc\xd1\x8b</a></li>\n<li><a href="/multfilmy/muzykalnye-m/">\xd0\x9c\xd1\x83\xd0\xb7\xd1\x8b\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb5</a></li>\n<li><a href="/multfilmy/priklyucheniya-m/">\xd0\x9f\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8e\xd1\x87\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f</a></li>\n</ul>\n<ul class="hm-col">\n<li><a href="/multfilmy/semejnye-m/">\xd0\xa1\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb9\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb5</a></li>\n<li><a href="/multfilmy/trillery-m/">\xd0\xa2\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd1\x8b</a></li>\n<li><a href="/multfilmy/uzhasy-m/">\xd0\xa3\xd0\xb6\xd0\xb0\xd1\x81\xd1\x8b</a></li>\n<li><a href="/multfilmy/fantastika-m/">\xd0\xa4\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0</a></li>\n<li><a href="/multfilmy/fehntezi-m/">\xd0\xa4\xd1\x8d\xd0\xbd\xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb8</a></li>\n</ul>\n</div>\n</li>\n<li><a href="/anime/">\xd0\x90\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb5</a>\n<div class="hidden-menu clearfix">\n<ul class="hm-col">\n<li><a href="/anime/">\xd0\x92\xd1\x81\xd0\xb5</a></li>\n<li><a href="/anime/netflix-a/">NETFLIX</a></li>\n<li>\xd0\x9f\xd0\xbe \xd0\xb3\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb4\xd1\x83:</li>\n<li><a href="/anime/2022-a/">2022</a></li>\n<li><a href="/anime/2021-a/">2021</a></li>\n<li><a href="/anime/2020-a/">2020</a></li>\n<li><a href="/anime/2019-a/">2019</a></li>\n<li><a href="/anime/2018-a/">2018</a></li>\n<li><a href="/anime/2017-a/">2017</a></li>\n</ul>\n<ul class="hm-col">\n<li>\xd0\x9f\xd0\xbe \xd0\xb6\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbc:</li>\n<li><a href="/anime/boeviki-a/">\xd0\x91\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd0\xb8</a></li>\n<li><a href="/anime/detektivy-a/">\xd0\x94\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\xd0\xba\xd1\x82\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd1\x8b</a></li>\n<li><a href="/anime/dramy-a/">\xd0\x94\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbc\xd1\x8b</a></li>\n<li><a href="/anime/komedii-a/">\xd0\x9a\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb8</a></li>\n<li><a href="/anime/kriminal-a/">\xd0\x9a\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb</a></li>\n<li><a href="/anime/melodramy-a/">\xd0\x9c\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb4\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbc\xd1\x8b</a></li>\n<li><a href="/anime/muzykalnye-a/">\xd0\x9c\xd1\x83\xd0\xb7\xd1\x8b\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb5</a></li>\n</ul>\n<ul class="hm-col">\n<li><a href="/anime/priklyucheniya-a/">\xd0\x9f\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8e\xd1\x87\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f</a></li>\n<li><a href="/anime/semejnye-a/">\xd0\xa1\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb9\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb5</a></li>\n<li><a href="/anime/sport-a/">\xd0\xa1\xd0\xbf\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd1\x82</a></li>\n<li><a href="/anime/trillery-a/">\xd0\xa2\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd1\x8b</a></li>\n<li><a href="/anime/uzhasy-a/">\xd0\xa3\xd0\xb6\xd0\xb0\xd1\x81\xd1\x8b</a></li>\n<li><a href="/anime/fantastika-a/">\xd0\xa4\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0</a></li>\n<li><a href="/anime/fehntezi-a/">\xd0\xa4\xd1\x8d\xd0\xbd\xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb8</a></li>\n</ul>\n</div>\n</li>\n\n</ul>\n<div class="search-wrap fx-1 to-mob">\n<form id="quicksearch" method="post">\n<input type="hidden" name="do" value="search" />\n<input type="hidden" name="subaction" value="search" />\n<div class="search-box">\n<input id="ajax_search" name="story" placeholder="\xd0\x92\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb8\xd1\x82\xd0\xb5 \xd1\x82\xd0\xbe\xd1\x87\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb5 (\xd0\xb1\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb7 \xd0\xbe\xd1\x88\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb1\xd0\xbe\xd0\xba!)" type="text" />\n<button type="submit"><span class="fa fa-search"></span></button>\n</div>\n</form>\n</div>\n<div class="btn-login btn js-login to-mob">\xd0\x92\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb9\xd1\x82\xd0\xb8</div>\n</div>\n</header>\n\n<div class="content">\n<main class="main">\n<div class="sect">\n<div class="sect-header fx-row fx-middle">\n <h1>\n\xd0\xa4\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd0\xbc\xd1\x8b \xd1\x81\xd0\xbc\xd0\xbe\xd1\x82\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82\xd1\x8c \xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9\xd0\xbd \xd0\xb1\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81\xd0\xbf\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd1\x82\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbe \xd0\xb2 HD \xd1\x85\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd1\x88\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbc \xd0\xba\xd0\xb0\xd1\x87\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\n</h1>\n\n<div class="filter-btn icon-left btn"><span class="fa fa-sliders"></span>\xd0\xa4\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd1\x82\xd1\x80</div>\n</div>\n<div class="sect"> <div class="filter-wrap">\n<form class="filter-box fx-row" data-dlefilter="dle-filter">\n<div class="fb-col fb-multi">\n<div class="fb-sect fb-sel">\n<select name="genre" multiple data-placeholder="\xd0\x92\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb1\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd1\x82\xd0\xb5 \xd0\xb6\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd1\x80">\n<option>\xd0\x91\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb3\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd1\x84\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f</option>\n<option>\xd0\x91\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba</option>\n<option>\xd0\x92\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xbd</option>\n<option>\xd0\x94\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\xd0\xba\xd1\x82\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2</option>\n<option>\xd0\x92\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb9</option>\n<option>\xd0\x94\xd0\xbe\xd0\xba\xd1\x83\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb9</option>\n<option>\xd0\x94\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb0</option>\n<option>\xd0\x94\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82\xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb9</option>\n<option>\xd0\x98\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd1\x87\xd0\xb5\xd1\x81\xd0\xba\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb9</option>\n<option>\xd0\x9a\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f</option>\n<option>\xd0\x9a\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb</option>\n<option>\xd0\x9c\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb4\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb0</option>\n<option>\xd0\x9f\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8e\xd1\x87\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f</option>\n<option>\xd0\xa1\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb9\xd0\xbd\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb9</option>\n<option>\xd0\xa2\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbb\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80</option>\n<option>\xd0\xa3\xd0\xb6\xd0\xb0\xd1\x81\xd1\x8b</option>\n<option>\xd0\xa4\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0</option>\n<option>\xd0\xa4\xd1\x8d\xd0\xbd\xd1\x82\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb8</option>\n</select>\n</div>\n<div class="fb-sect fb-sel">\n<select name="country" multiple data-placeholder="\xd0\x92\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb1\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd1\x82\xd0\xb5 \xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd1\x83">\n<option value="\xd0\xa1\xd0\xa8\xd0\x90">\xd0\xa1\xd0\xa8\xd0\x90</option>\n<option value="\xd0\xa0\xd0\xbe\xd1\x81\xd1\x81\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f">\xd0\xa0\xd0\xbe\xd1\x81\xd1\x81\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x90\xd0\xb2\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f">\xd0\x90\xd0\xb2\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x90\xd0\xb2\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f">\xd0\x90\xd0\xb2\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x90\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb1\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f">\xd0\x90\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb1\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x90\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb4\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0">\xd0\x90\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb4\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x90\xd1\x80\xd0\xb3\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd1\x82\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0">\xd0\x90\xd1\x80\xd0\xb3\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd1\x82\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x90\xd1\x84\xd0\xb3\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd">\xd0\x90\xd1\x84\xd0\xb3\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x91\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd1\x83\xd1\x81\xd1\x8c">\xd0\x91\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd1\x83\xd1\x81\xd1\x8c</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x91\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd0\xb3\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f">\xd0\x91\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd0\xb3\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x91\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb3\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f">\xd0\x91\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb3\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x91\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f">\xd0\x91\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x92\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb1\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f">\xd0\x92\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb1\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x92\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb3\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f">\xd0\x92\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb3\xd1\x80\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x92\xd1\x8c\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbc">\xd0\x92\xd1\x8c\xd0\xb5\xd1\x82\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbc</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x93\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0">\xd0\x93\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x93\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f">\xd0\x93\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x93\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f (\xd0\xa4\xd0\xa0\xd0\x93)">\xd0\x93\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f (\xd0\xa4\xd0\xa0\xd0\x93)</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x93\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd\xd0\xba\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb3">\xd0\x93\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd\xd0\xba\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb3</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x93\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd1\x86\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f">\xd0\x93\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd1\x86\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x93\xd1\x80\xd1\x83\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f">\xd0\x93\xd1\x80\xd1\x83\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x94\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f">\xd0\x94\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x98\xd0\xb7\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c">\xd0\x98\xd0\xb7\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x98\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f">\xd0\x98\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x98\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb4\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f">\xd0\x98\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb4\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x98\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f">\xd0\x98\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x98\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd">\xd0\x98\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x98\xd1\x80\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f">\xd0\x98\xd1\x80\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x98\xd1\x81\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f">\xd0\x98\xd1\x81\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x98\xd1\x81\xd0\xbf\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f">\xd0\x98\xd1\x81\xd0\xbf\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x98\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f">\xd0\x98\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x9a\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb0\xd1\x85\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd">\xd0\x9a\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb0\xd1\x85\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x9a\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb1\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb6\xd0\xb0">\xd0\x9a\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb1\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb6\xd0\xb0</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x9a\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb0">\xd0\x9a\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb0</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x9a\xd0\xb0\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80">\xd0\x9a\xd0\xb0\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x9a\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f">\xd0\x9a\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x9a\xd0\xb8\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9">\xd0\x9a\xd0\xb8\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x9a\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbb\xd1\x83\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb1\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f">\xd0\x9a\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbb\xd1\x83\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb1\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x9a\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd1\x8f \xd0\xa1\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd1\x8f">\xd0\x9a\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd1\x8f \xd0\xa1\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd1\x8f</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x9a\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd1\x8f \xd0\xae\xd0\xb6\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd1\x8f">\xd0\x9a\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xb5\xd1\x8f \xd0\xae\xd0\xb6\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb0\xd1\x8f</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x9a\xd1\x8b\xd1\x80\xd0\xb3\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb7\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd">\xd0\x9a\xd1\x8b\xd1\x80\xd0\xb3\xd1\x8b\xd0\xb7\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x9b\xd0\xb0\xd1\x82\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f">\xd0\x9b\xd0\xb0\xd1\x82\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x9b\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd">\xd0\x9b\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x9b\xd0\xb8\xd1\x82\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0">\xd0\x9b\xd0\xb8\xd1\x82\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x9b\xd1\x8e\xd0\xba\xd1\x81\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb1\xd1\x83\xd1\x80\xd0\xb3">\xd0\x9b\xd1\x8e\xd0\xba\xd1\x81\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbc\xd0\xb1\xd1\x83\xd1\x80\xd0\xb3</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x9c\xd0\xb0\xd0\xba\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb4\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f">\xd0\x9c\xd0\xb0\xd0\xba\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb4\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x9c\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f">\xd0\x9c\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9\xd0\xb7\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x9c\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0">\xd0\x9c\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x9c\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xba\xd0\xba\xd0\xbe">\xd0\x9c\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd0\xbe\xd0\xba\xd0\xba\xd0\xbe</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x9c\xd0\xb5\xd0\xba\xd1\x81\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0">\xd0\x9c\xd0\xb5\xd0\xba\xd1\x81\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd0\xb0</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x9d\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb4\xd1\x8b">\xd0\x9d\xd0\xb8\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb4\xd1\x8b</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x9d\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0\xd1\x8f \xd0\x97\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f">\xd0\x9d\xd0\xbe\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0\xd1\x8f \xd0\x97\xd0\xb5\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb4\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x9d\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb3\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f">\xd0\x9d\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb5\xd0\xb3\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x9e\xd0\x90\xd0\xad">\xd0\x9e\xd0\x90\xd0\xad</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x9f\xd0\xb0\xd0\xba\xd0\xb8\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd">\xd0\x9f\xd0\xb0\xd0\xba\xd0\xb8\xd1\x81\xd1\x82\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbd</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x9f\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb3\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9">\xd0\x9f\xd0\xb0\xd1\x80\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb3\xd0\xb2\xd0\xb0\xd0\xb9</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x9f\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd1\x83">\xd0\x9f\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd1\x83</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x9f\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd1\x88\xd0\xb0">\xd0\x9f\xd0\xbe\xd0\xbb\xd1\x8c\xd1\x88\xd0\xb0</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x9f\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd1\x82\xd1\x83\xd0\xb3\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f">\xd0\x9f\xd0\xbe\xd1\x80\xd1\x82\xd1\x83\xd0\xb3\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbb\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f</option>\n<option value="\xd0\x9f\xd1\x83\xd1\x8d\xd1\x80\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe \xd0\xa0\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd0\xbe">\xd0\x9f\xd1\x83\xd1\x8d\xd1\x80\xd1\x82\xd0\xbe \xd0\xa0\xd0\xb8\xd0\xba\xd0\xbe</option>\n<option value="\xd0\xa0\xd1\x83\xd0\xbc\xd1\x8b\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f">\xd0\xa0\xd1\x83\xd0\xbc\xd1\x8b\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f</option>\n<option value="\xd0\xa1\xd0\xa1\xd0\xa1\xd0\xa0">\xd0\xa1\xd0\xa1\xd0\xa1\xd0\xa0</option>\n<option value="\xd0\xa1\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xb1\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f">\xd0\xa1\xd0\xb5\xd1\x80\xd0\xb1\xd0\xb8\xd1\x8f</option>\n<option value="\xd0\xa1\xd0\xb8\xd0\xbd\xd0\xb3\xd0\xb0\xd0\xbf\xd1\x83\xd1
```

Как привести к понятному тексту символы внутри html тегов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
req = Request('https://lord4.lordfilm.lu/filmy/', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:105.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/105.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()

str_ = webpage.decode("utf8")
print(str_)
```

Или так:

```
req = Request('https://lord4.lordfilm.lu/filmy/', headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:105.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/105.0'})
resp = urlopen(req)
data = resp.read().decode(resp.headers.get_content_charset())
print(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл ответ:

```
req = Request('https://lord4.lordfilm.lu/filmy/', headers={'User-Agent': 
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:105.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/105.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
html = bs4.BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'html.parser')
```